# Difference between flushright and raggedleft

Tags: horizontal-alignment

What is the difference between `flushright` and `raggedleft`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`\begin{flushright}...\end{flushright}` is the environment form of `\raggedleft`. They are the equivalent of `\begin{center}...\end{center}` and `\centering`, respectively. Here's an example using the two:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\listfiles\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{flushright}\lipsum[2]\end{flushright}
\lipsum[3]

\newpage
\lipsum[4]
{\raggedleft\lipsum[5]\par}
\lipsum[6]
\end{document}
```

In particular, note the extra space around `flushright`.

Comment: Use of trivlist is a key difference, so {flushright} isn't really the environment form of \raggedleft.  I just had a case where the implicit use of {flushright} messed things in a way that was hard to debug., Suppose your page output style includes a page header that uses \flushright or \flushleft in some way.  If page 1 breaks as a result of new material that invoves another trivlist -- in my case a theorem environment from the standard amsart.cls -- the trivlist opening (Theorem 1.1) gets tacked onto the page 1 header, instead of staying with the trivlist text at the top of page 2!

Comment: @SilvioLevy — something about that doesn't sound quite right to me; I wouldn't think it's possible for interaction between the paragraph builder and the page builder in the way that you describe. But it's been a long time since I looked into code of that sort, so I probably shouldn't comment really...

Answer (score 16):

The environments internally are based on a list (exactly a »trivlist«) with fixed list parameters. That's why they cause the extra vertical space before and behind that Will mentioned. The amount of this space is determined by the length `\topsep`. Regarding the [center](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/latex2e-help-texinfo/latex2e.html#center) environment this can be very annoying when used to center float objects.

Comment: Which is why you should use `\centering` to centre floats rather than `{center}`. (Or, better, use something like floatrow to automatically centre them.)

Comment: Yes, and I should have added that.