# Missing \item's when writing unamed chapters using memoir's veelo style

Tags: memoir

I was working on modifying the `veelo` chapter style given by [`memoir`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir) and found out a `LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.` would come up when using a named chapter after an unnamed one. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\chapterstyle{veelo}

\begin{document}
\chapter{}

\chapter{Second}

\chapter{Third}

\chapter*{Fourth}

\end{document}
```

The error is raised on `\chapter{Second}`, but not on the other chapters. After tinkering around with the code on Sec. B.1.5 of `memoir`'s user manual I was able to reproduce the error with a simpler custom style. Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\makechapterstyle{style}{
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\HUGE\bfseries\flushright}
}
\chapterstyle{style}

\begin{document}
\chapter{}

\chapter{Second}

\chapter{Third}

\chapter*{Fourth}

\end{document}
```

It seems the error disappears if the command `\flushright` is removed. How can I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3644/144146), `flushright` is actually an environment. The command equivalent is `raggedleft`. I'm not fully sure about the details of why this works, but changing this in the MWE seems to fix the problem. Here's the new MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\makechapterstyle{style}{
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\HUGE\bfseries\raggedleft}
}
\chapterstyle{style}

\begin{document}
\chapter{}

\chapter{Second}

\chapter{Third}

\chapter*{Fourth}

\end{document}
```